# Rails: using helper methods from config

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

How would I go about using helper methods from a config file?

This may be unorthodox but it makes sense in the context that I need it. The helper method I need is used to properly format URLs in one of my views. The config file is the initializer for the sitemap_generator Gem, where I need the helper method to format some of the URLs.

I tried require, which does indeed include the module, but get undefined method for module when I call it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does your method need to be in a helper? Can't you put it in a class in your `lib` folder?

```
# lib/my_url_helper.rb
class MyUrlHelper
  def self.proper_format(...)
    ...
  end
end

# app/helpers/application_helper.rb
def proper_format(*args)
  MyUrlHelper.proper_format(*args)
end
```

Tip / personal experience: Most of the time you do something "unorthodox" you are trying to solve the wrong problem.

Comment: Working fine! Does not have to be a helper, but since I use the method in my views it makes sense. I'm unsure about how unorthodox this solution is, since I do need helper methods to format URLs for my sitemap, used in a similar fashion as is used in my views.

Answer (score 2):

This is how you include your helper in the SitemapGenerator config :

`SitemapGenerator::Interpreter.send :include, ApplicationHelper`